# React set state inside FullCalendar's datesSet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, primereact

I was wondering if i can pass a callback to the datesSet's method of FullCalendar, callback that will set a state.
I tried this already, and it ended up making my page reload untill the browser asked me to close the page or wait. Also, i have seen that FullCalendar documentation recommends using day-header or day-cell render hooks, but they are not what i'd really need.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can pass a callback function in a setState. Actually this is very common to do it.

```js
setState(prevState => prevState + 1)
```

For example.

Comment: I created myself another react project containing just a FullCalendar and a state to change inside the datesSet and it worked! Also, i figured out the problem in my project:
-> If inside FullCalendar's options, i have the  "locales: [roLocale]", the page will not be able to load anymore.

Thanks for  your help!